# Change type of a column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to change the DataType of a mySQL table from float to DECIMAL:

```
ALTER TABLE t_tapes ALTER COLUMN price DECIMAL(15,6);
```

but I got an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECIMAL(15,6)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Have to change only `ALTER` before `COLUMN` TO `MODIFY`
LIKE

```
ALTER TABLE t_tapes MODIFY COLUMN price DECIMAL(15,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

need Modify instead of Alter

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;


ALTER TABLE t_tapes 
MODIFY COLUMN price DECIMAL(15,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQl Query for Change data type of Mysql Column

```
 ALTER TABLE `db-name`.`table-name` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `column-name` `column-name` DECIMAL(15,6);
```